# How to rewrite a constraint with sum of convex and concave components to satisfy DCP rule?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cvxpy, disciplined-convex-programming, cbc, scip

suppose that decision variable is `X` with `N` dimensions, and one type of the constraint is `y = y0-sum(max(0,x)*b)-sum(min(0,x)*a)`, where the dimension of `x` is from 1 to `N` which means that there are `N` constraints, and the `y` should be less than `y_min` and be greater than `y_max`, i.e. `y_min <= y0-sum(max(0,x)*b)-sum(min(0,x)*a) <= y_max`.

In `cvxpy`, it could be write as `y0 - cp.sum(cp.pos(x[:i])*b) + cp.sum(cp.neg(x[:i])*a)`,

however, `-cp.sum(cp.pos(x[:i])*b)` is a `concave` expression, `cp.sum(cp.neg(x[:i])*a)` is a `convex` expression, and the sum of them would not satisfy the DCP rule.

Is it possible to rewrite this type of constraint to follow the DCP rule?

(although we could use `dccp` to solve it.)

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but your concave expression can be made linear using extra binary variables.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, could you give me some examples? Thanks

Comment: $$\begin{aligned} &y^+ - y^- = y \\ & y^+ \le M\delta\\& y^- \le M(1-\delta)\\&y^+,y^- \ge 0 \\ & \delta\in \{0,1\}\end{aligned}$$ This formulation should really be in your toolbox as it is not uncommon.

Comment: ok, I understand, I will try, Thanks @ErwinKalvelagen